# How much does an EXEC cost?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I inherited some legacy code in which every stored procedure is implemented **twice**: One for **single** "case id" provided via an input param, the other for a **list** of "case ids" provided by a *table type* input param.

I have been given a task to "improved maintainability" by re-implementing every "single id" SP by (re)using the "list SP". Quite tedious but nothing rocket science:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SingleIdProc]
    @CaseId BIGINT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TTIdsList dbo.TTIdsList
        INSERT INTO @TTIdsList(id) 
        VALUES (@CaseId)

        EXEC [dbo].[SingleIdProcByList]
             @CaseIds = @TTIdsList
    END
RETURN 0
```

It works (correctly!), but now the DBA complains that this hurt performance so much that he had to revert all such "fixed" SPs to their prior version...

So my questions are:

1. How much such does an indirection call cost?
2. How do I measure performance difference myself?

Comment: What do the execution plans look like for the scalar version and for the TVP version?

Comment: It is not about `EXEC` as such. Most likely execution plan for a specific ID is quite different from execution plan for the table parameter. When given a simple `bigint` parameter optimizer is able to find a better plan.

Comment: @MartinSmith both scalar and vector versions are implemented identically (except for the input param, of course, which mandates a JOIN by CaseId, to run the same exact code on a table rather than on a single BIGINT).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov How do I find out what the *actual* execution plans are (after the optimizer has done its thing)?

Comment: Have a look: [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx) In SSMS there is a button/option  to show Actual execution plan. I would also recommend a [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) (even free version is very good).

Comment: You may find this [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) useful.

Comment: Additionally I'd ask DBA for details of performance issues. Does single run of each proc _hurts performance_ or may be `SingleIdProc` is executes thousands times and this is a problem area.

Comment: Thank you all. @VladimirBaranov Please post your comments as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in performance is likely to be caused not by `EXEC` as such.

Most likely execution plan for a specific ID is quite different from execution plan for the table parameter. When given a simple `bigint` parameter optimizer may be able to find a better plan.

You may find this article about [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) useful.

To see the actual execution plans in SSMS there is a button/command to show/include actual execution plan. See [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

I would also recommend a [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view). Even free version is very good. You can run both variants in it together and you'll see all stats next to each other. It helps to see what is going on.